# How to get rid of goto's?

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and I would like to know if there are ways to not use `goto`s in my code here.

```
using System;

namespace project1

{
    class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        start:

        Console.Clear ();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        int rannum;
        int input;

        Random r = new Random ();
        rannum = r.Next (1, 1001);

        Console.WriteLine ("Guess the number!");

        game:
        input = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

        if (input == rannum) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Congrats!");
            Console.WriteLine ("Press any key to go again...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            goto start;
        } 
        else if (input <= rannum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Guess higher!");
            goto game;
        } 
        else if (input >= rannum)
        {   Console.WriteLine ("Guess lower!");
            goto game;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that `goto`s are bad (apparently) so how do I do this without them?

Comment: Well, `while` loops would be a good start... you might also want to consider extracting at least some of the code into a separate method. (Hint "play a single game" sounds like a reasonable method to me.)

Comment: what will be the Exit condition? when will the game Ends?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into some tutorials on while loops.

And about the exit condition, I'm just learning and this isn't an actual game just a preview of what i can do. Sort of like a debug build.

Comment: I'm kinda curious to know how you even found out about gotos before you found out about while loops and methods.

Comment: @siride beat me to it.

Comment: I am familiar with batch and i used gotos in batch a lot, so i just used it in c # too

Answer (score 3):

Jon commented while I was forming this answer, obviously great minds think alike.

Anyway, here's how you can eliminate the `goto start`:

```
public static void Main()
{
     Random r = new Random ();
     string again;
     do {
         PlayOneGame( r.Next(1, 1001) );
         Console.WriteLine("Play again?");
         again = Console.ReadLine();
     } while (!again.ToLower().StartsWith('n'));
}

public static void PlayOneGame(int rannum)
{
    Console.Clear ();

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

    int input;



    Console.WriteLine ("Guess the number!");

    game:
    input = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

    if (input == rannum) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Congrats!");
        return;  // goes back to the caller, Main, but without using goto
    } 
    else if (input <= rannum)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Guess higher!");
        goto game;
    } 
    else if (input >= rannum)
    {   Console.WriteLine ("Guess lower!");
        goto game;
    }
}
```

Now, can you get rid of `goto game` in a similar way?

Note that I've also arranged things to only create one `Random` object and continue to use it no matter how many games are played -- it's not a good idea to keep creating new RNGs, the starting state is not terribly random.

Answer (score 0):

I just did something like this and it's working, am I still doing anything wrong?

```
public static void Main ()
    {
        PlayGame ();

        Console.WriteLine ("Press 'n' key to exit the application, press any other key to play again.");
        string again = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey ());
        if (again == "n") {
            Environment.Exit (0);
        }

        PlayGame ();
    }

    public static void PlayGame ()
    {
        Console.Clear ();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;

        int randomNumber;
        int userInput;
        int gameover = 0;

        Random number = new Random ();
        randomNumber = number.Next (1, 1001);

        Console.WriteLine ("Guess the number!");

        while (gameover != 1) 
        {
            userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (userInput == randomNumber) {
                Console.Clear ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Congrats!");
                return;
            } else if (userInput <= randomNumber) {
                Console.Clear ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Guess Higher!");
            } else if (userInput >= randomNumber) {
                Console.Clear ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Guess Lower!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be asking follow up questions as answers to your original post, they probably won't get noticed or answered. This code is much better than your original post, mostly because it doesn't contain any goto commands ;-)

Comment: Because you don't have a loop in `Main()`, the game will only be played twice (after the second game you won't ask to play again).  You also are still creating a new RNG for every random number you need, which is not recommended.  Were there parts of my answer you didn't understand?  Finally, your variable `gameover` is useless, because the loop exits from a `return` statement and not from the `gameover != 1` condition.